# Using BETWEEN Condition Without Including Two Dates

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there a simple way of using BETWEEN but not including the two dates you want to check between? I noticed if you use BETWEEN it includes the start and end date itself. I've been working on a booking system and want to stop guests booking dates in between another booking or overlapping another booking.

E.g. if there's a booking for 20th May until the 25th May I don't want anyone to be able to book those dates regardless of the start and end date of the new booking. I do, however, want users to be able to have their end date on the same day as a different booking's start date or the start date on the same day as a different booking's end date.

Originally I had:

```
SELECT id 
  FROM table 
 WHERE (? BETWEEN arrive_date AND depart_date) 
    OR (? BETWEEN arrive_date AND depart_date)
```

The first ? is for the new arrive date and the second ? is for the new end date.

But when checking it included the start and end date then I tried to work out the correct formula and got this:

```
SELECT id FROM table 
 WHERE (? BETWEEN arrive_date - INTERVAL 1 DAY AND depart_date - INTERVAL 1 DAY) 
    OR (? BETWEEN arrive_date + INTERVAL 1 DAY AND depart_date - INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

It seemed to be fine but then I noticed if I book, for example, 9th November and 10th November I can then also book 6th 15th November.

I thought what I had was correct and I am still working it all out but if someone can see where I am going wrong that would be helpful!

Comment: But why bind yourself to BETWEEN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is a row in the table with `arrive_date` less than the queried departure date and `depart_date` greater than the queried arrival date then you will get as result `'booked'`, else you will get `'free'`:

```
SELECT CASE
  WHEN EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 
    FROM `table` 
    WHERE :depart_date > arrive_date AND :arrive_date < depart_date
  ) THEN 'booked'
  ELSE 'free'
END result
```

Replace `:arrive_date` and `:depart_date` with the dates that you will pass as parameters.

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=138f8add2a89e36a0f3d0959456bfbb4).

Comment: Totally forgot about <= conditions. Although this didn't work. I tested by making a booking end date on the same date as another booking's start date and returned saying it couldn't do so.

Comment: @TheWelshManc for the case that you describe the condition `:depart_date <= arrive_date` is `TRUE` making the conditions in the WHERE clause also `TRUE`. So how does it not work? Post sample data to clarify what you want.

Comment: So I tested earlier by having 9th November booked until 11th November booked. I tried to book 7th November to 9th November and it didn't work. I then tested two random dates without any overlapping and it didn't work. Basically if it finds any dates within the table it will say that there's already a booking and return an error page.

Comment: @TheWelshManc `9th November` is not a date and it is not comparable. What is the data type of the columns?

Comment: The columns are date. I have a booking start date and a booking end date. They are formatted as YYYY-MM-DD so 9th November is 2021-11-09.

Comment: @TheWelshManc then you must be doing something wrong because the query works fine as you can see here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d1d8dd2bc82714b312e35bc2fba15f4e

Comment: I think you've misunderstood my question. Let's say for example, I already have a booking between 9th November and 11th November, I want to stop others being able to book those dates too or any dates that overlap but I still want them to be able to book on the start and end date. Using BETWEEN includes the start and end date meaning I had to work out how to allow the start and end date to be booked.

Comment: @TheWelshManc this is why in my previous comment I asked you what is your expected output. Post sample data and expected results that cover all cases.

Comment: Thank you and sorry if I confused you. I wasn't sure how to word the question originally. I wanted to ask the question sooner but didn't know how to ask it.